# Using Dimension Feature in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, dimensions

I would like to use the Dimension Feature tool in ArcGIS - this button [image] as I want to have a label on every side of some polygons (they are all reasonably simple polygons).

When I click on my polygon to add the dimensions (and don't move or click the mouse again), they come up like this which is how I want them:

[image]

However as soon as I click the left mouse button to place them, they go like this:

[image]

Am I missing an option somewhere? it does not allow me to select 'Dimension Feature' in the Construction tools section of the create features dialog. Its only available as a button (that I found by adding the button manually). The closest construction tool I can select is Dimension Edge, but that means I have to add dimensions for each edge of the polygon. Its a slower process.

Comment: I think the problems is coming with ArcGIS system on your pc and need to re install it

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what is wrong with my machine? As I have just installed ArcGIS 10.2 (and this includes a uninstall of 10.1 SP1). It still doesn't work.

Comment: Why my ArcGIS create feature box does not allow me to add dimension?? There is only a Construction Tools box...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Dimension Feature tool, which seems to be the only one that will dimension every side of a feature at once, *only* gives vertical or horizontal dimensions.  It will not give aligned dimensions.

The tool you want to use that will dimension each side (unfortunately only one-at-a-time) is either the **Simple Aligned Dimension** [image], which produces dimensions that look the same as your first image, or the **Aligned Dimension** [image] which produces the same dimensions but gives the extra option of off-setting away from the feature.

Simple Aligned Dimension:

[image]

Aligned Dimension:

[image]